# How to Change jQuery Scrollbar Scroller Color to Black Using CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to change my scroller color from gray to black using jQuery Scrollbar. I'm certain I have to modify the css file, I just don't know how. Here's the CodePen that shows what I'm starting with: https://codepen.io/sunbliss/pen/aZvgGP.

Here's my code:

```
/*************** SCROLLBAR BASE CSS ***************/
 
.scroll-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}
 
.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: auto !important;
}
 
.scroll-wrapper > .scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
 
.scroll-element {
    display: none;
}
.scroll-element, .scroll-element div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
 
.scroll-element.scroll-x.scroll-scrollx_visible,
.scroll-element.scroll-y.scroll-scrolly_visible {
    display: block;
}
 
.scroll-element .scroll-bar,
.scroll-element .scroll-arrow {
    cursor: default;
}
 
.scroll-textarea {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-top-color: #999999;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea {
    border: none !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100% !important;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;
    overflow: scroll !important;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.scroll-textarea > .scroll-content > textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
 
 
 
 
/*************** TEXTAREA STYLES ***************/
 
.textarea-scrollbar {
    height: 250px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Where do I put color: black;?

Thanks in advance.

Neo

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `scrollbar-color` property, this way:

```
.scroll-element {
    scrollbar-color: red green;
}
```

As you can see, there is 2 colors defined: the first applies to the thumb of the scrollbar, the second to the track.

---

**ATTENTION**
Currently you can use it only in few browsers: [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar-color) more information about the status of support; [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color) detailed info about this property.

Comment: I need iOS Safari support. If there's no support for a black scroller, then why does this codepen show one? https://codepen.io/iamandrewluca/pen/vmZpON